# Read more Links do not have descriptive text

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, anchor, lighthouse

I have a page which contains a list of items. Each item contains a 'Read more' link that points to a different page. But when I run the lighthouse tool on that page, it complains that links do not have a descriptive text. Now I cannot change the Read more text here.

```
<a href="link 1">Read more</a>
<a href="link 2">Read more</a>
<a href="link 3">Read more</a>
```

Is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: check this article https://web.dev/link-text/

Comment: Why can't you change the text there?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.
Attribute `aria-label` **does not works**, lighthouse still display issue.
I fixed it by adding **hidden detailed text inside link**.

```
<a href="link 1">Read more<span class="screen-reader-text">Details</span></a>

<style>
.screen-reader-text {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    word-break: normal;
}
</style>
```

Note about `.screen-reader-text`: this CSS grabbed from wordpress default Twenty Seventeen theme.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) in order to provide more descriptive text to Assistive Tech such as a screen reader.

```html
<a href="link 1" aria-label="some more descriptive text that explains the link">Read more</a>
```

Assistive tech will read the contents of the `aria-label` out instead of "Read More".

Bear in mind that the text you enter should be enough to know where the link will take you and not context dependent (the link text should make sense on its own) if possible.

Comment: I tried that but it still complains and the funny thing is that if I change the text to Read this then it's fine as it seems like they are blacklisting some words mentioned here [web.dev/link-text/](https://web.dev/link-text/)

Comment: Well if you are using an `aria-label` with a decent description you are certainly doing it correctly and it may be the tool misreporting. Is the page publicly accessible, if it is do you want to share a URL to it? I will happily have a look.

Comment: The alternative would be visually hidden text within a span, I can cover that if you can't get a solution with `aria-label`. It is actually a more robust solution, but it is a little more work that is all.